# pyautogui error when using pyautogui.displayMousePosition()

Tags: python, pyautogui

[I am trying to lean how to use pyautogui and I got stuck on this. I've reinstalled python twice and deleted all the files related to python on my computer, then reinstalled and I still got this error message, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. The file it says it needs is there, but it cant access it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw2mA.png)

Comment: from the error it seems that you need to install pillow. did you try to reinstall pillow maybe this link will help you https://wp.stolaf.edu/it/installing-pil-pillow-cimage-on-windows-and-mac/

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyautogui import *

try:

    displayMousePosition()

except AttributeError:

    from sys import *
    from subprocess import *
    call([executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "Pillow"])
```

Try this code and tell me if it works